# Memory increase on each orientation change, using two different layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-orientation

I'm using different layouts for portrait and landscape modes.
Is memory increasing each time orientation is changed if I'm using two different layouts?
How to use same memory or free activity memory load previously?
I used:

```
<activity android:name=".LoginOnline"
 android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
```

in activity in manifest file and override `onconfigurationchanged` method to prevent activity recreate but memory is still not released!

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    String userr = user.getText().toString();
    String passs = pass.getText().toString();
    boolean rme = rememberme.isChecked();
    setContentView(R.layout.loginonline);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginonline);
    user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    rememberme = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.remeberme);
    user.setText(userr);
    pass.setText(passs);
    rememberme.setChecked(rme);
    login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            login(user.getText().toString(), pass.getText().toString());
            if (rememberme.isChecked()) {
                saveLoginDetails();
            } else {
                removeLoginDetails();
            }
        }
    });
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

But still the memory increases each time the orientation changes. Why?

Comment: Memory increase is fine, that's the way the garbage collector works, it doesn't kick in immediately. The question is what happens when you are changing orientation over and over again?  I would recommend viewing -  [http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk]  It's a google IO session on memory management on Android. It should give you some directions and tools to use.

Comment: i have already go through this video but still no resolution found?if i m using same layout for portrait and landscape mode then memory not increase even we rotate thousand times but if i m using different layout memory increase on each orientation?so plz give me a resolution??

Comment: 50% memory optimization done...Typeface also leads to memory leak and resolved in given link **Aussom!!**  http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9904