# Memory Management in Activity using Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT and getApplicationContext()?

Tags: android, memory-management, android-intent, memory-leaks, android-activity

I m using below code to start another activity in my application -

**Intent itab = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TabhostScreen.class);
itab.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(itab);**

how can i manage memory in this context because Activity resume each time when we call Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT.

so how would we manage memory?????

Comment: i want to use different layout for an activity on orientation change so how can i do without memory leak?????

Comment: why are you relating Intent Flags and device orientation with memory management?

Comment: i m using this intent flag so activity not call oncreate it only resume and bring to front hence memory not increase it work fine ? but on orientation change if i m using different layout memory increases ?

Comment: The comment is getting out of comment limit so i am posting this as an answer.Hope it's fine with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT flag so that multiple instances of the same activity is not created and activity is brought to the front in same state without popping out other activities from the history stack. Memory management is not the concern here so far as android documents suggests.                  
When you are rotating the device then your activity is recreated and using different layout is perfectly fine in fact it is a **good practice** in android. Hence memory requirement will increase. You can stop this behavior by fixing the screen orientation in the manifest file.

Comment: plz look at this question...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12006040/memory-increase-on-each-orientation-change-using-two-different-layouts

Comment: thanks for the link. I looked into the post. And you are right about the increased memory consumption. But during device orientation you will have to make some compromise between memory consumption and complexity. When you let the activity restart on config changes then android handles the view updates and many other things for you but when you are handling the config changes yourself you will have to handle theses complexities. And as android document suggests you should always use this as the last resort.

Comment: Follow this link for more insight on this issue: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange